# ListView not responding to scroll but touch

Tags: android, listview

When my listview stops scrolling,i call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on it. I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` also when

1. the user touches the listview (list is not scrolling)
2. removes his finger from the list (list is not scrolling)

But when the listview stops scrolling and i try to scroll it again immediately, it doesnt responds. It takes 1-2 sec for it to again respond to scroll. Not getting any clue

[Code](http://pastebin.com/reFdTZVA) for onTouchListener

```
 listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if(mScrollStateOfListView==OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {


                        if (!adapter.getAllItemsVisible()) {

                            doThings();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else if (adapter.getAllItemsVisible() && adapter.getHighlightCurrentMonth()) {
                            doThings();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }

                    }
                    else if(mScrollStateOfListView==OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                        listBeingTouched.set(true);
                    }


                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    if(mScrollStateOfListView==OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        doThings();
                        listBeingTouched.compareAndSet(true,false);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    else if(mScrollStateOfListView==OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){

                        listBeingTouched.compareAndSet(true,false);
                    }



                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

[Code](http://pastebin.com/gkPiK0Um) for onscrollListener

```
 listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            }

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                mScrollStateOfListView=scrollState;
                if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && !listBeingTouched.get()) {
                    listBeingTouched.set(true);
                    doThingsAndNotifyAdapterDataSet()

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code that would be relevant?

Comment: Ok @codeMagic i am posting on pastebin

Comment: No, post the *most relevant* code in your question. We shouldn't need to go off-site to see your code (at least not for a partial snippet). If you want to link the entire code in a paste, fine, but the important parts should be here.

Comment: I am posting the code for onTouch() and onScroll() only

Comment: @codeMagic posted the code

Comment: *"We shouldn't need to go off-site to see your code (at least not for a partial snippet). If you want to link the entire code in a paste, fine, but the important parts should be here."* </facepalm>

Comment: @codeMagic pasted it here. The code i posted is necessary to get the context. Now i dont see, which part of this code i can omit

Comment: And this is fine to get started. We may need more but you should start with something in your post. Anyway, what is `listBeingTouched`?

Comment: Its an AtomicBoolean which i set when the user touches the list

Comment: And what does `doThingsAndNotifyAdapterDataSet()` do? Anything that might slow it down?

Comment: In that function, i loop over all the visible rows,and set one row( closest to the middle of the screen) in the middle of the screen